# How to split a simple Lisp-like code to tokens in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, token

Basically, the language has 3 list and 3 fixed-length types, one of them is string.
This is simple to detect the type of a token using regular expressions, but splitting them into tokens is not that trivial.

String is notated with double-quote, and double-qoute is escaped with backslash.

EDIT:

Some example code

```
{
     print (sum (1 2 3 4))
     if [( 2 + 3 ) < 6] : {print ("Smaller")}
}
```

Lists like

- () are argument lists that are only evaluated when necessary.
- [] are special list to express 2 operand operations in a prettier
  way.
- {} are lists that are always evaluated. First element is a function
  name, second is a list of arguments, and this repeats.
- anything : anything [ : anything [: ...]] translate to argument lists that have the elements joined by the :s. This is only for making loops and conditionals look better.

All functions take a single argument. Argument lists can be used for functions that need more. You can fore and argument list to evaluate using different types of eval functions. (There would be eval functions for each list model)

So, if you understand this, this works very similar like Lisp does, it's only has different list types for prettifying the code.

EDIT:
@rici

`[[2 + 3] < 6]` is OK too. As I mentioned, argument lists are evaluated only when it's necessary. Since `<` is a function that requires an argument list of length 2, `(2 + 3)` must be evaluated somehow, other ways it `[(2 + 3) < 6]` would translate to `< (2 + 3) : 6` which equals to `< (2 + 3 6)` which is and invalid argument list for `<`. But I see you point, it's not trivial that how automatic parsing in this case should work. The version that I described above, is that the `[...]` evaluates arguments list with a function like `eval_as_oplist (...)` But I guess you are right, because this way,  you couldn't use an argument list in the regular way inside a `[...]` which is problematic even if you don't have a reason to do so, because it doesn't lead to a better code. So `[[. . .] . .]` is a better code, I agree.

Comment: Ummm... could you give some example code (and by code, I mean input)? Also could you share the "trivial" detection regex? And what you have tried to do the splitting?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it should be tagged "functional programming," try "parsing" instead?  And if it looks like an S expression, you might simply trying using an S expression parser, or modifying one?

Comment: Shouldn't that be if `[[ 2 + 3 ] < 6 ]`? If not, I don't understand the syntax of `[...]`

Comment: Also: why is it `{print ("Smaller")}` and not just `{print "Smaller"}`? Or, alternatively, why isn't it `{print ((sum (1 2 3 4)))...` ? (IOW, is this really an improvement over just having a single way of spelling `(`? :) )

Comment: Draw a state machine to "parse" the tokens.  State0 is the start state; nothing has been seen.  In each state, add arcs for characters you might see in that state, and transition to a "next" state that abstract represents what has been seen ("sequence of digits").  For the language you defined, I'd guess 10 or 15 states is enough.  It is trivial to convert such a state machine to C or C++ code.   Note this answers the *tokenizing" question, not how to parse such a series of tokens; for that, you can code a recursive descent parser easily to process the tokens produced by the state matchine.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the code simple as possible, but I think that having conditional statements and loops that look this way, is an improvement. `{ print ("Smaller")}` is the same as `{print "Smaller"}` because `"Smaller"` is the same as `"Smaller" : ()`. Single element argument list act like a value and vice versa. I agree to all of your points to keep the language simple as possible, because this is my goal.

Comment: OK. I still don't think I get all of this, but that's ok. As I said in another comment, writing a grammar will probably help you clarify, both for yourself and for others. I would have thought that `"Smaller"` was the same as `() : "Smaller"` but perhaps you don't intend for `()` lists to nest, in which case they don't seem to me to be first-class objects. Also, I wonder about higher-order-functions: how do you represent the application of a function which is the result of calling another function? Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Flex (possibly with Bison) or ANTLR, which has a C++ output target.

Since google is simpler than finding stuff on my own file server, here is someone else's example:

http://ragnermagalhaes.blogspot.com/2007/08/bison-lisp-grammar.html

This example has formatting problems (which can be resolved by viewing the HTML in a text editor) and only supports one type of list, but it should help you get started and certainly shows how to split the items into tokens.

Comment: I have already thought of it, and I'm starting to admit to myself that this language is not simple enough for me to write a parser without using a parser generator.

Comment: @kdani you don't need to use a parser-generator. It's nearly trivial to write a recursive descent parser, and hand-rolled lexers for languages like yours would be a cinch.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that simple languages are a good chance to practice with parser generators.

Comment: I agree with siride. Currently, because of various problems with bison I am seriously considering rewriting a much more complex grammar (a subset of SQL) as a recursive descent parser. ANTLR is much better than bison or yacc, but you start depending on Java, which can be an issue as well.

Comment: While it's true that the parser for your language should be quite simple, I'd suggest using a parser generator anyway, because writing a grammar provides a better explanation of the syntax than a parser. Once you've debugged the grammar, you'll have a syntax you can share with other people, and you'll know that the parser implements the grammar. A hand-written parser does not offer these advantages. Either `bison` or `ANTLR` should work fine. Unlike @piokuc, I think `bison` is great, fwiw, but tastes vary and you should use the one you find easier to learn.

Comment: This is not about tastes, I have concrete issues with bison. I have no problem with the metalanguage defined by yacc and bison, it's nice; the way you are supposed to write semantic actions, although designed for C, works nice with C++, no problems here. But I hate that using yacc or bison: 1) you cannot pass anything to the parse routine, 2) you cannot parse a text sitting in memory, only files, 3) parsers are not re-entrant. In theory, bison has some extensions (to yacc's baseline functionality), to do these things, but try using them... both yacc & bison implementations are crap, sorry.

Comment: @piokuc: I've used the extra argument feature of bison, without any issues. I don't think it's fair to say that you can't parse a text sitting in memory, since bison only deals with tokens; gnu-flex certainly allows you to provide a text string, although it does copy it behind your back. I agree with you about re-entrancy; I've always used lemon for re-entrant parsers and it has some nice extensions to the grammar metalanguage, too; but I think bison is trying to improve in this regard. Help would probably be welcome :)

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't trying hard enough.. The thing is, I am required to develop software which has no other dependencies other than standard Unix tools and the C++ standard library. So if there is only lex & yacc on a Unix box, my software should build with it. Crazy, I know. So the bison's extensions are not really of much use to me. Many thanks for pointing me to Lemon, I didn't know it, looks very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inventing your own "Lisp-like, but simpler" language, you should consider using an existing Lisp (or Scheme) implementation and embedding it in your C++ application.

Although designing your own language and then writing your own parser and interpreter for it is surely good fun, you will have hard time to come up with something better designed, more powerful and implemented more efficiently and robustly than, say, Scheme and it's numerous implementations.

Chibi Scheme: http://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/ is particularly well suited for embedding in C/C++ code, it's very small and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) would be suitable for this task *provided* you could construct a PEG-compatible grammar for the language you're proposing. It's not obvious from the examples as to whether or not this is the case.

More specifically, Spirit has a generalized AST called [utree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/utree.html), and there is example code for parsing symbolic expressions (ie lisp syntax) into utree.

You don't have to use utree in order to take advantage of Spirit's parsing and lexing capabilities, but you would have to have your own AST representation. Maybe that's what you want?